# access preferences of native android on phone gap android

Tags: eclipse, cordova, sharedpreferences

I have made an application on native android platform using eclipse...in that i get a authentication token by logging into app and I save this token in shared preferences and next time when the user starts the app...using authentication token the login screen is skipped.(one time login)

Now I have made that same application in phone gap so now I want to access that token...I also have the key for shared preference but don't know how to access the same in phone gap...because I don't want the current users to login again.

Is it possible to access key of one platform on another.?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **cordova plugin add https://github.com/edelworksgithub/SharedPreferences.git** for SharedPreferences.

Here is an example, how to use this:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', () => {
  function createPref(filename, mode){

    sharedpreferences.getSharedPreferences(filename, mode, successHandler, errorHandler);
}

function successHandler(result){

    alert("SUCCESS: \r\n"+result );
}

function errorHandler(result){

    alert("ERORR: \r\n"+result );
}
}
```

Put Values

```
function putValue(key, value, type){

    switch(type){
        case "string":
        sharedpreferences.putString(key, value, successHandler, errorHandler);
        break;
        case "int":
        sharedpreferences.putInt(key, value, successHandler, errorHandler);
        break;
        case "long":
        sharedpreferences.putLong(key, value, successHandler, errorHandler);
        break;
        case "boolean":
        sharedpreferences.putBoolean(key, value, successHandler, errorHandler);
        break;
    }
}
```

Get Values

```
function getValue(key, type){
    switch(type){
        case "string":
        sharedpreferences.getString(key, successHandler, errorHandler);
        break;
        case "int":
        sharedpreferences.getInt(key, successHandler, errorHandler);
        break;
        case "long":
        sharedpreferences.getLong(key, successHandler, errorHandler);
        break;
        case "boolean":
        sharedpreferences.getBoolean(key, successHandler, errorHandler);
        break;
    }

}
```

Also you can read complete documentation at: https://github.com/edelworksgithub/SharedPreferences